# Is there an equivalent to phpinfo in spring framework (Java)?

Tags: java, php, spring

Is there an easy way to see an aggregated dump of all information (variables, drivers, paths, sessions, etc) about a webserver running spring... Similar to what phpinfo() does for PHP sites.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Spring Actuator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Spring boot actuator` for this.include below dependency in `pom.xml`, Change version with yours!

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

refer below endpoints which actuator offers for different purposes.

[End points](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)